# Set label name of button created with MobGUI

Tags: user-interface, button, mobile, label, livecode

On livecode, you can set the label of the button easily with:

```
      set the label of btn "test" to "This is a Test"
```

But how to set the label of button that is created using MobGUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobGui buttons have the mgText property which you can get and set.

Something like the following should allow you to change the text of a mobGui button

```
set the mgText of group "test" to "this is a test"
```

More info on this can be found in the following mobGui documentation-

http://mobgui.com/doc.php?docId=10